# If the limit of a series is 0 and it is decreasing does it also converge ?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question is about the alternating series test.  That says an alternating series converges if the limit is 0 AND it is decreasing BUT wouldn't this be true regardless of whether or not the series is alternating?

I assume not accept I am having trouble thinking of an examples and thought someone would be kind enough to show an example of a series that has a limit of 0 and is decreasing but is not converging due to the fact that it is not alternating.

Comment: The series $\sum \frac{1}{n} = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + \cdots$ does not converge.

Comment: If it was true, there would be no alternating series test.

Comment: Oh...I see now....thank you ....I feel stupid....the alternating add and subtracts....that makes a big difference........thank you for clearing that up.   I will delete the question in a few....

Comment: You have a lot of strange things bouncing around, such as "limit of a series" and "it is decreasing" I'm guessing you are confusing the series with its terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $\sum a_n$ the condition $a_n\to 0$ is a **necessary** but not sufficient condition.

The classical example is of course given by the harmonic series $\sum \frac1n$.